# Applying multiple functions to each line of the input

Tags: j

I have 2 normalization functions: norm1 and norm2.

```
norm1 =: (- <./) % >./ - <./
norm2 =: %(>./@:|)
```

I want to apply these two functions to each line of the following input like this:

```
input123 =: i. 2 10

|:(norm1 0{input123),.(norm2 1{input123)

0 0.111111 0.222222 0.333333 0.444444 0.555556 0.666667 0.777778 0.888889 1
0.526316 0.578947 0.631579 0.684211 0.736842 0.789474 0.842105 0.894737 0.947368 1
```

Instead of using `{` to extract each line from the `input123`, is there any simpler way to apply multiple verbs to each line of an input array? Maybe by making an array of verbs and apply them to each line of the input?

It doesn't have to be a line, it can be each element(`"0`), or matrix(`"2`) for a higher-dimensional input data, etc

Thank you for your advice in advance. = ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually do exactly what you'd like to do with a [cyclic gerund](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/CyclicGerund):

```
   norm1`norm2"1 input123
       0 0.111111 0.222222 0.333333 0.444444 0.555556 0.666667 0.777778 0.888889 1
0.526316 0.578947 0.631579 0.684211 0.736842 0.789474 0.842105 0.894737 0.947368 1
```

Comment: Hello Julian, I have tried this, but the result is not as same as yours. Mine returns the names of verbs not the numbers. should I use different verbs or input shape?

Comment: @KevinChoi you're doing something different, or (less likely) you're using an older version of J and it behaved differently. My example exactly as written and with the exact code in your example, works fine. the \` is backtick, or grave, under the \~. The `"1" is the rank operator and required.

Comment: Hello Julien! Your code is perfectly working after I installed the latest version (J701 -> J901) . Thank you so much. I have to update occasionally lol